# GDB shows 'no line number information' for the address pointed by the instruction pointer

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, gdb, shared-libraries, objdump

My program is crashing and this is the segfault message. `python3[26871]: segfault at 4cac ip 00007fe49938248a sp 00007fe498a64820 error 4 in libswsscommon.so.0.0.0[7fe499359000+7a000]`

address should be (IP - loaded address of shared lib). (7fe49938248a - 7fe499359000) = 0x2948A.

When I try to get the info, gdb says 'no line number info'

```
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libswsscommon.so.0.0.0...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/94/d57d3ce6dd6901ddf7f7d8985a8334c7622fc6.debug...done.
done.
(gdb) info line *0x2948A

No line number information available for address 0x2948a
```

How is it possible? Does it have anything to do with the start address which is greater than `0x2948A`, as shown by `objdump -f`

objdump -f /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libswsscommon.so.0.0.0

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libswsscommon.so.0.0.0:     file format elf64-x86-64
architecture: i386:x86-64, flags 0x00000150:

HAS_SYMS, DYNAMIC, D_PAGED

start address 0x0000000000034d60
```

Comment: Even if you build *your* code with debug information and have it available, libraries and external applications usually don't have it. You need to go up the callstack to *your* code to see what happens there. Especially since it's more likely the problem is in your code and not on the libraries you use.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The library is not a standard one. my colleagues developed it. I'm able to see line info for other addresses. e.g.                                   (gdb) info line *0x40000
Line 2290 of "/usr/include/c++/8/bits/basic_string.h"
   starts at address 0x3ffbe <swss::DebugShCmdToken::executeCmd(DebugShCmdCtx*, s

Comment: Have you tried using the *actual* IP virtual address of `0x7fe49938248a`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I couldn't do that. because I don't know which python3 executable crashed(hundreds of python processes had run & I'm left with the damaged setup). So I've to use gdb for the  library only

Comment: Are you able to delay the crash until you can attach GDB to the library, that is its process?

Comment: Logging and core dumps! Logging so you can see what's happening and narrow down the location of the crash. Core dumps so you can load it later and get a chance to get more information. And remember to build with debug information even for the libraries you release, and until the issue is resolved perhaps even with optimizations disabled.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  Thanks. yeah, I need to try alternatives like logging, core, gdb.. But I'm curious to know the answer for the question that why couldn't I find the line number info from the instruction pointer when I'm able to get the info for other addresses. What is wrong here?